# Why mysql don't start in ubuntu server?

Tags: ubuntu, mysql, innodb

I edit mysql config for remote connect, I paste there

```
bind_address = 0.0.0.0
```

After it i tryed to restart (sudo /etc/init.d/mysql restart or start) but I see fail of it in both commands.

in logs i have this:

> InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11 InnoDB: Check that you do
>   not already have another mysqld process InnoDB: using the same InnoDB
>   data or log files.

I move back bind_address = 127.0.0.1, but can't start mysql too.
Why? What I need to do?

Comment: 1) Did it ever work? 2) You are _sure_ there isn't another process running?

Comment: I restart the server and all start work again! So, don't know what it was.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MySQL is already running. Kill the existing MySQL server processes manually before trying to start it again.